# Python random number generator program not printing results

Tags: python

I made a small program that is designed to generate a random number between 0 and 1, and based on what it is print out a statement (In this case "Missed", "1 point" or "3 points") as well as the number that was actually made. The program generates the numbers fine, but I can't get it to print out the statements, is there something I overlooked here?

```
def zeroG():
 from random import *
 n=random()
 #print n
 if(0>=n>0.3):
   print("miss")
 elif(0.3>=n>0.7):
   print("1 point")
 elif(0.7>=n>=1):
   print("3 points")
 print n
```

Comment: if you're only using `random.random`, just `from random import random`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change all of your `>` to `<`.  Consider the first `if` statement, `0 >= n > 0.3` is equivalent to `0 >= n and n > 0.3`, or in words "`n` is less than or equal to zero and greater than 0.3".  Of course what you actually want is "`n` is greater than or equal to zero and less than 0.3", which is `0 <= n < 0.3`.

Full code:

```
from random import random

def zeroG():
  n = random()
  if 0 <= n < 0.3:
    print "miss"
  elif 0.3 <= n < 0.7:
    print "1 point"
  elif 0.7 <= n <= 1:
    print "3 points"
  print n
```

Comment: Thankyou, I've been looking at this code for ages now and missed that completely

Answer (score 1):

Look at your conditions: they are backwards. You need

```
if(0<=n<0.3):
   print("miss")
 elif(0.3<=n<0.7):
   print("1 point")
 elif(0.7<=n<=1):
   print("3 points")
 print n
```

Comment: And don't forget to set seed for random